# Warning message with miceadds::load.data

Tags: r

I have the following text file 1.txt

```
line 1

line 3
```

And I am running the following code:

```
miceadds::load.data( "1.txt", type="txt", load_fun=readLines)
```

I got what I want exactly plus two warning messages:

```
*** Load 1.txt
[1] "line 1" ""       "line 3"
Warning messages:
1: In max(grep(type1, files, value = TRUE)) :
  no non-missing arguments, returning NA
2: In (function (con = stdin(), n = -1L, ok = TRUE, warn = TRUE, encoding = "unknown",  :
  incomplete final line found on '1.txt'
```

I know I can suppress the warnings, but would like to know why it happened and how to fix it elegantly.